# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str it is showing in if statement

Tags: python-3.x

Type error obtained from the below code.

Code below is to subset the list

```
lst = ['abc', 'Bcd', 'abf', 'bbc', 'Anv']

w = 0

for i in lst:

    if int(lst[i][0].isupper()) != 0:

        w += 1
print(w)
```

Comment: Replace `lst[i]` with `i`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Thanks For the help...

Answer (score 2):

You are already taking the element of the list with i. So you just need to subset its element. Below is the code which fixes the error.

```
lst = ['abc', 'Bcd', 'abf', 'bbc', 'Anv']

w = 0

for i in lst:

    if int(i[0].isupper()) != 0:

        w += 1
print(w)
```

> Result : 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```py
lst = ['abc', 'Bcd', 'abf', 'bbc', 'Anv']
w = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if int(lst[i][0].isupper()) != 0:
        w += 1
print(w)
```

**Explaination:** The problem in your code is that when you are doing `for i in lst` it's actually getting values like 'abc', 'Bcd', .. etc. in each iteration. Then you are doing `lst[i]` which means `lst['abc']`, `lst['Bcd']`, and so on.. Which is wrong, that's why you are getting the error.